# How to restrict which hardware instances a user can access using ibmcloud CLI

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Looking for a way to restrict a user to specific hardware instances via ibmcloud CLI. So far I've tried

```
ibmcloud sl user detail-edit USER_ID --template '{"hardware": [{"id": HW_ID}]}'
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You would like to restrict the "size" of the instance the user can create?  I see the command "ibmcloud sl hardware create" has an option --size value.  Do you want to restrict the value of the size parameter for the user?

Comment: Yes, the example worked. Before:
`Name           BA SRE Monitor`
after:
`Name           Test Testerson`
Any ideas what template to use to modify allowed hardware?
Thank you, Daniel!

Comment: I'd like to restrict what hardware this user has access to. So that only specific hardware instances show up when I execute:

`ibmcloud sl user detail USER_ID --hardware`

Thank you, Powell! @PowellQuiring

Answer (score 0):

Use the following ibmcloud cli command:

```
ibmcloud sl call-api SoftLayer_User_Customer removeBulkHardwareAccess --init 11111 --parameters "[[22222]]"
```

Replace 11111 for the userId you want to restrict access and 22222 for your hardwareId.

Or you can try through rest api call, see the following example:

Method: POST

```
https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_User_Customer/11111/removeBulkHardwareAccess
```

Body: Json

```
{
  "parameters":[
    [22222]
  ]
}
```

Reference:
https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_User_Customer/removeBulkHardwareAccess/

Comment: Excellent! This worked! Thank you!
Used the following command to add hardware access:
`ibmcloud sl call-api SoftLayer_User_Customer addBulkHardwareAccess --init USER_ID --parameters "[[HW_ID1, HW_ID2, HW_ID3, ...]]"`

where HW_IDs are integers.

Comment: yes, you can use that ibmcloud command to add specifics hardware instance access, but if the user has permissions to access all hardware, the same will be able to access all the hw except the ones that you removed. See the user permissions through: ```ibmcloud sl user permissions USER_ID```. If the user has this permission "ACCESS_ALL_HARDWARE", I recommend that you remove that permission and just add the specifics hw ids.

Comment: Great point! Thank you! That's in effect what we do by only restricting access to specific hardware for users who don't have "ACCESS_ALL_HARDWARE" permission.